# Bayes' Theorem with multiple random variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I'm reviewing some notes regarding probability, and the section regarding Conditional Probability gives the following example:

$P(X,Y|Z)=\frac{P(Z|X,Y)P(X,Y)}{P(Z)}=\frac{P(Y,Z|X)P(X)}{P(Z)}$

The middle expression is clearly just the application of Bayes' Theorem, but I can't see how the third expression is equal to the second.  Can someone please clarify how the two are equal?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

We know
$$P(X,Y)=P(X)P(Y|X)$$
and
$$P(Y,Z|X)=P(Y|X)P(Z|X,Y)$$
(to understand this, note that if you ignore the fact that everything is conditioned on $X$ then it is just like the first example).

Therefore
\begin{align*}
P(Z|X,Y)P(X,Y)&=P(Z|X,Y)P(X)P(Y|X)\\
&=P(Y,Z|X)P(X)
\end{align*}
Which derives the third expression from the second.

(However I don't have any good intuition for what the third expression *means*. Does anyone else?)

Answer (score 16):

We have

$$P(X,Y\mid Z) \tag1$$

Considering X and Y as a single event, we call them A. Now we have

$$P(A\mid Z) = P(X,Y\mid Z) \tag2$$

Using the Joint Probabilities Rule, we have

$$P(A,Z) = P(A\mid Z)\times P(Z) \tag3$$

So we can say that

$$P(A\mid Z) = \frac{P(A,Z)}{P(Z)} \tag4$$

We know that

$$P(A,Z) = P(Z,A) \tag5$$

Again using the Joint Probabilities Rule, we have

$$P(Z,A) = P(Z \mid A)\times P(A) \tag6$$

We defined $P(A)$ as the following

$$P(A) = P(X,Y) \tag7$$

Again using the Joint Probabilities Rule, we have

$$P(X,Y) = P(X\mid Y)\times P(Y) \tag8$$

Plugging $(8)$ into $(7)$, we have

$$P(A) = P(X\mid Y)\times P(Y) \tag9$$

Plugging $(9)$ into $(6)$, we have

$$P(Z,A) = P(Z\mid A)\times P(X\mid Y)\times P(Y) \tag{10}$$

Plugging $(10)$ into $(5)$ we have

$$P(A,Z) = P(Z\mid A)\times P(X\mid Y)\times P(Y) \tag{11}$$

Plugging $(11)$ into $(4)$, we have

$$P(A\mid Z) = \frac{P(Z\mid A)\times P(X\mid Y)\times P(Y)}{P(Z)} \tag{12}$$

Plugging $(12)$ into $(2)$, we have

$$P(X,Y\mid Z) = \frac{P(Z\mid A)\times P(X\mid Y)\times P(Y)}{P(Z)} \tag{13}$$

Observe that in $(13)$, using the Joint Probabilities Rule, we have

$$P(X,Y) = P(X\mid Y)\times P(Y) \tag{14}$$

Since we defined $P(A)$ is $P(X,Y)$, we have

$$P(A) = P(X\mid Y)\times P(Y) \tag{15}$$

Plugging $(15)$ into $(13)$, we have

$$P(X,Y\mid Z) = \frac{P(Z\mid A)\times P(A)}{P(Z)} \tag{16}$$

Observe that in $(16)$, using the Joint Probabilities Rule, we have

$$P(Z\mid A) = \frac{P(Z,A)}{P(A)} \tag{17}$$

Plugging $(17)$ into $(16)$, we have

$$P(X,Y\mid Z) = \frac{P(Z,A)}{P(Z)} \tag{18}$$

Now observe the following

$$P(Z,A) = P(Z,X,Y) = P(Y,Z,X) \tag{19}$$

Similar to what we did at the beginning, treating $Y$ and $Z$ as a single event and using the Joint Probabilities Rule, we have

$$P(Y,Z,X) = P(Y,Z\mid X)\times P(X) \tag{20}$$

Plugging $(20)$ into $(19)$, we have

$$P(Z,A) = P(Y,Z\mid X)\times P(X) \tag{21}$$

Plugging $(21)$ into $(18)$, we have

$$P(X,Y\mid Z) = \frac{P(Y,Z\mid X)\times P(X)}{P(Z)} \tag{22}$$

I don't know if this clarifies or complicates things more but nevertheless I wanted to include this here as well.

Right now, I can't prove why treating multiple joint events as if they were a single event is "legal".

Comment: Please edit your answer by adding $\rm\LaTeX$, for some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Can you explain why (5) P(A,Z) = P(Z,A). I don't understand why this is the same

Comment: @MrBonjour Oh, actually I don't have a rigorous proof for that but it simply states that: "Probability of occurrence of A AND B together is the same as probability of occurrence of B AND A together.". As I said, I don't have a rigorous proof for it but both sides of the equation state: "The probability of occurrence of two (given) events *at* *the* *same* *time*.". Since they are occurring at the same time, I don't think that specifying an order to this has a meaning. So this might be a casual explanation for that.

Comment: Ok thank you. Actually I'm agree with your explanation. By the way your previous example give me a good grasp of the equation. Thank you again

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm glad that my answer helped someone.

Comment: P(A,Z)=P(Z,A) because events Z and A are independent, not because they are simultaneous or not. If A and Z are not independent, then this equality is not true. Example of not independent events that occur simultaneously: A = encounter a person with long hair, Z = encounter a woman

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to follow the following argumentation
$$P(Z|X,Y)P(X,Y) = \frac{P(X,Y,Z)}{P(X,Y)}P(X,Y) = P(X,Y,Z)=\frac{P(X,Y,Z)}{P(X)}P(X)=P(Y,Z|X)P(X).$$

Comment: you are being unnecessarily tactless. we are here to help and get help, not to show off..

Comment: I have to say that I found this explanation the easiest to follow, even so for the original, one-line version preceding the edit.  Clearly, some folks might have taken offense with @royli prefacing his answer with "Isn't this obvious?" but for me, when explained that way, it _was_ obvious!

Comment: I see this type of language all the time in lecture notes from the CS dept at my university... I think it's a stylistic trend. however, it drives me crazy. Oftentimes the claim is not "easy" or "trivial to see" or "obvious" in my opinion.